# In Python, get another attribute of a class instance from within a class attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

How or can I do the following? Please note that while I declare b_class, I don't always directly instantiate b_class but is instantiated by a library.

```
class a_class:
  def some_method(self):
    """
    get the class instance of b_class in which a_class is instantiated
    using that instance, get var1
    perform some action based on var1
    """

class b_class:
  var1 = "init by the constructor or a method"
  a_inst = a_class()
  """
  other attributes
  """
```

Comment: This makes no sense as asked, and implies a fundamental misunderstanding of OOP.

Comment: What do you mean by "the class instance"? There can be many instances of a class, or none at all. That's kind of the point of classes.

Comment: I understand it like this: `b_class` instances have a `a_inst` attribute which is an instance of class `a_class`. The OP wants to know if that specific instance of `a_class` can know what instance of `b_class` it has been assigned *to*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes that's exactly what I meant. Modified the comment in the code to clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: @user1928896: It's called containment; `a_class` instances are contained in `b_class` instances, via the `a_inst` attribute. You wanted to know if the containee (an instance of `a_class`) can know about it's container somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, not without passing a reference to the instance of `b_class` when you call `some_method` or when you create your `a_class` instance.

You could store references to that `a_class` instance anywhere, and because of that, you cannot, in Python, know from within the instance method where it has been assigned.

So, do this:

```
class a_class:
  def __init__(self, parent):
    self.parent = parent

  def some_method(self):
    self.parent.var1

class b_class:
  def __init__(self):
      self.var1 = "init by the constructor or a method"
      self.a_inst = a_class(self)
```

Now instances of `a_class` 'know' about their parent, and can reference them via the `self.parent` instance variable.

Comment: +1. I'm not positive this is what the OP wants, but if it is, this is the simplest and most idiomatic way to do it, and very nicely explained.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying: Don't do it this way; it is a horrible, overly complicated hack, and the correct way is to pass an `a_class` instance to your `b_class` instance when you instantiate the latter, as Martijn has nicely illustrated.

That said, given the assumption that each of your `a_class` instances will be associated with at most one `b_class` instance, you can fish it out by asking the garbage collector.

```
import gc

class A(object):
    def get_my_B(self):
        # iterate over objects that point to us
        for ref in gc.get_referrers(self):
            if type(ref) is dict:   # could be instance's __dict__
                instances = [x for x in gc.get_referrers(ref) if type(x) is B]
                # if we have been found in the __dict__ of exactly one instance
                # and that __dict__contains a reference to us, we found our B
                if len(instances) == 1:
                    if getattr(instances[0], "__dict__", None) is ref:
                        if ref.get("a", None) is self:
                            return instances[0]
        return None

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()

b = B()
assert b.a.get_my_B() is b
```